# invalid implicit conversion from contract to address requested contract

Tags: solidity, addresses, error

I am using this function to create a new contract instance of Match contract which takes 4 parameters.
However i am getting this error message "invalid implicit conversion from contract to address requested contract".
I have no idea how to address this.

```
function newMatch(uint _matchId,uint _noOfGames,uint _oddsOfA, uint _oddsOfB) public returns(address newContract)
      {
        Match c = new Match(_matchId,_noOfGames,_oddsOfA,_oddsOfB);
        contracts.push(c);
        return address(c);
      }
```

Comment: What is `contracts`???

Comment: its an array of addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `contracts` is an array of addresses, change this:

```
contracts.push(c)
```

To this:

```
contracts.push(address(c))
```